# Exclude two values from a table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I need help with the following table where I need to exclude everything from the column "limit" that is not equal to "UNLIMITED" or the value is below "365" AND RESOURCE_NAME ='PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME'.

```
**PROFILE**             **RESOURCE_NAME**              **LIMIT**
CONSULTA_DISC       PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME        200
DBA_PROFILE         PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME        UNLIMITED
SISTEMAS            PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME        375
CONSULTA_MASIVOS    PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME        200
CONSULTA            PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME        200
DEFAULT             PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME        UNLIMITED
```

I appreciate the help in advance.
thanks

Comment: Are you trying to create a constraint on a table?  Or limit the results of a query?  It isn't obvious from your description which of the rows you want to exclude.  My guess is that you just want to exclude the third row from a query.

Comment: Hi, I want to exclude from the "LIMIT" column the values that are "unlimited" and higher than 365

Comment: Would be better to make the column nullable, convert the UNLIMITED to NULL and then change the column to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `WHERE` condition like

```
WHERE ("LIMIT" = 'UNLIMITED' OR CAST("LIMIT" AS INT) > 365)
AND RESOURCE_NAME = 'PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME'
```

Comment: still the wrong result, i ran the query SELECT PROFILE, LIMIT 
FROM DBA_PROFILES 
WHERE (LIMIT <> 'UNLIMITED' OR LIMIT > '365') 
AND RESOURCE_NAME = 'PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME';

Comment: @Christian, my bad; didn't noticed that limit a varchar column. You will need to cast it before comparing. See edit in answer. Again, per your post you want `limit = unlimited` since you said *I need to exclude everything from the column "limit" that is not equal to "UNLIMITED"*. Try the exact query in answer.

Comment: trying to run the update but i am getting Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression.           WHERE (LIMIT = 'UNLIMITED' OR CAST(LIMIT AS INT) > '365') AND RESOURCE_NAME = 'PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME'

Comment: @Christian, there is no error in the where part. may be it's in other part of your query. post the entire query you are running.

Comment: I am trying to run this query in Oracle and I am getting the Syntax error with the following query: 

SELECT PROFILE
FROM DBA_PROFILES 
WHERE (LIMIT <> 'UNLIMITED' OR CAST(LIMIT AS INT) < '365')
AND RESOURCE_NAME = 'PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME';

Comment: @Christian, change your query like below `SELECT "PROFILE" FROM DBA_PROFILES WHERE (LIMIT <> 'UNLIMITED' OR CAST(LIMIT AS INT) < 365) AND RESOURCE_NAME = 'PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME';` you need to escape profile since it's a keyword and after casting to INT you shouldn't use quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @Table1 TABLE 
    (PROFILE varchar(16), RESOURCE_NAME varchar(19), LIMIT varchar(9))
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (PROFILE, RESOURCE_NAME, LIMIT)
VALUES
    ('CONSULTA_DISC', 'PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME', '200'),
    ('DBA_PROFILE', 'PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME', 'UNLIMITED'),
    ('SISTEMAS', 'PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME', '375'),
    ('CONSULTA_MASIVOS', 'PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME', '200'),
    ('CONSULTA', 'PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME', '200'),
    ('DEFAULT', 'PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME', 'UNLIMITED')
;

select * from @Table1

where LIMIT <> 'UNLIMITED' and CAST(LIMIT as INT) >= 365
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this result by using UPDATE Statement

```
Create TABLE LimitTable
    (PROFILE nvarchar(max), RESOURCE_NAME nvarchar(max), LIMIT nvarchar(max))


INSERT INTO LimitTable VALUES
    ('CONSULTA_DISC', 'PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME', '200'),
    ('DBA_PROFILE', 'PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME', 'UNLIMITED'),
    ('SISTEMAS', 'PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME', '375'),
    ('CONSULTA_MASIVOS', 'PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME', '200'),
    ('CONSULTA', 'PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME', '200'),
    ('DEFAULT', 'PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME', 'UNLIMITED');

 Update LimitTable
 Set Limit = ''
 where PROFILE = 'CONSULTA_DISC' 
 OR PROFILE = 'CONSULTA_MASIVOS'
 OR PROFILE = 'CONSULTA'

 Select * from LimitTable
```

This will get rid of those values you don't need from that LIMIT column

Here is the live demo with result http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/de2f8/1/0